# TabHost - get rid of drop shadow?

Tags: android

I have a basic TabActivity. On android 2.1 (and possibly older versions), it looks like a drop shadow is added below the tab widget. On 2.3, this shadow is not present. Is there a way to turn that shadow off completely? Maybe something like "android:fadingEdgeLength=0" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the white strip? I've hacked past this by calling this method inside **onTabChanged**

Let you class implement **OnTabChangeListener**

```
 private static TabHost mTabHost;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Instantiate your tab host normally
 }


 @Override
     public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
         removeWhiteStrip(mTabHost);
 }

 /**
 * Hack
 * @param tabHost
 */
private static void removeWhiteStrip(TabHost tabHost) {
    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) tabHost.getChildAt(1);

    Field mBottomLeftStrip;
    Field mBottomRightStrip;

    try {
        mBottomLeftStrip = tw.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBottomLeftStrip");
        mBottomRightStrip = tw.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBottomRightStrip");

        if (!mBottomLeftStrip.isAccessible()) {
            mBottomLeftStrip.setAccessible(true);
        }

        if (!mBottomRightStrip.isAccessible()) {
            mBottomRightStrip.setAccessible(true);
        }

 // This is a blank drawable basically a 1x1 png with 100% alpha
        mBottomLeftStrip.set(tw, MyApp.getInstance().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank));
        mBottomRightStrip.set(tw, MyApp.getInstance().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank));

    } 
    catch (java.lang.NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // possibly 2.2
        try {
            Method stripEnabled = tw.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setStripEnabled", boolean.class);
            stripEnabled.invoke(tw, false);

        } 
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // tut tut shouldn't catch generic exception and ignore it
            // but we do because this is a hack
    }

}
```

Enjoy

Comment: Hi yeah - I'm using the light theme, so that shadow appears black instead of white I think. The hack isn't working, shadow still is shown. It's actually only shown if one of the children is Activity, not ListActivity, very strange. Argh, android...

Comment: I was able to get rid of it by setting <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> in my app's theme. So obvious, I can't believe I didn't think of doing that!

Comment: Hmm wonder why it wasn't working. You did have it on onTabChanged() ? As I think it needs to keep refreshing it. But GZ finding he fix!